# Why is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, off-topic

I'm just wondering why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122914/download-a-file-using-curl-from-a-php-server/) was closed? It has code that the asker has tried, there is an accepted answer that provides the code that the asker needed (a particular `curl` option), and it has obviously come in handy for people since as it has upvotes on both question and answer, but it's been closed as off-topic.

Just trying to understand what the reasoning might have been.

Comment: Probably because curl is not programming-related. It's like asking a question about FTP or Gopher. And I don't even know that curl falls into the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: And yet there's a tag for it and close to 50,000 questions when you search for curl. It just seems like that was a perfectly reasonable question. Are you suggesting it belongs on SuperUser?

Comment: There is also a CURL library for programming. But scripting with curl is on-topic IMO too.

Comment: Well I'm currently using curl to diagnose a problem with my programming, and I very often see it recommended in answers on SO so it certainly fits with "tools commonly used" in my opinion.

Comment: I use curl to verify http status codes and do automated route-testing. So, yes, I think it falls under "software tools commonly used."

Comment: Well thank you, all. At least I now know the reasoning, even if I don't agree with it.

Comment: It has three votes to reopen. Seems you're not the only one. ;)

Comment: The question [was successfully reopened](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9122914/revisions). And people say Meta doesn't work.

Comment: @Akam That's an invalid assumption. The overwhelming majority of questions that I close are those in my field, concerning technologies that I know well. People don't vote to close questions because they don't know the answer—on the contrary, that would be a reason to upvote and leave them open. Rather, they vote to close because a question does not meet our guidelines, set out rather explicitly in the FAQ.

Comment: @CodyGray: I am not talking about you and I knew that many good people here spending time for helping other people, also, closing bad question is helpful because helps us to be clean, but I realized that there were many cases that people down-voting without any sense! see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688387/simple-php-mysql-create-table-script/17688425#17688425) what's confusing me is votes changes the validity and correctness of the answers, bad answers with high votes makes the scenario very worst!

Comment: Well that didn't stay open long - closed again on Jul 23rd! No wonder people say Meta doesn't work. I note the new close reason it suggests asking the question on SuperUser (where there are 46 questions tagged curl, as against 9,500 on StackOverflow). How does a question get migrated to another SO site?